# Strange votes on my account

Tags: support

I have some strange votes from serial downvotes and reversed votes that do not really fit a timeline - and some of the votes are still there.

The timeline is as follows

> Today

[image]

> Yesterday

[image]

> Two days ago

[image]

All the downvotes (I'm unsure about the vote on "Access JSON Array...") are the result from serial downvoting, what I don't understand is

1. Why were 7 votes reversed when there were only 4 to reverse at that time?
2. Where do the other three come from, did the moderator who reversed them already know they'll come?
3. The 3 votes from today are still there, why is that?

I'm not sure if there were more votes from the past reversed that would fit to the 7 questions/answers. Was it that?

---

Note that the script didn't handle the votes, I flagged them and a moderator did.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Any moderator feel free to correct or supercede this, it is only an approximation based on what I know about this.

> Why were 7 votes reversed when there were only 4 to reverse at that
>   time?

The reversal happened at 22:34, which indicates it was done by a staff member by hand and not the script. As animuson pointed out [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370785/strange-votes-on-my-account/370788?noredirect=1#comment607628_370788):

> It doesn't necessarily mean 7 were targeted. The manual tools do not
>   allow for picking and choosing which [of a user's] votes [to your
>   account] get reversed. It becomes an
>   all or nothing deal. And sometimes we would choose not to reverse 4
>   downvotes that look targeted if the user has cast, say, 20 upvotes to
>   your account. Since it's all or nothing, wiping the downvotes would
>   also wipe the upvotes, and the loss from 20 upvotes far outweighs the
>   gain from reversing 4 downvotes

So the user who voted for you had some more votes on your posts that were caught in the crossfire.

> Where do the other three come from, did the moderator who reversed
>   them already know they'll come?

We don't know, you don't know. Could be the same person, could not. If you suspect they're serial voting, flag a post of your own for investigation (But wait until a day after first to see if the script gets them).

The staff member who reversed them is presumably not able to see the future when they reversed them (yesterday 22:34) so no.

> The 3 votes from today are still there, why is that?

They happened after a staff member looked at your account to correct any foul play. Staff members do not consistently monitor for ongoing voting in such cases. The script only runs at the end of the day. They're still here because nobody has checked them yet and the script hasn't run.

Comment: That's pretty much my suspicion too, yeah

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean 7 were targeted. The manual tools do not allow for picking and choosing which votes get reversed. It becomes an all or nothing deal. And sometimes we would choose *not* to reverse 4 downvotes that look targeted if the user has cast, say, 20 upvotes to your account. Since it's all or nothing, wiping the downvotes would also wipe the upvotes, and the loss from 20 upvotes far outweighs the gain from reversing 4 downvotes.

Comment: @animuson This is interesting. Is this behavior of CM tools documented somewhere? So if I understand this correctly, if I have 20 votes cast on user X's posts, 10 up and 10 serially down, then y'all doing anything would result in a -80 reputation net loss for the user?

Comment: Right, and that's happened before in cases where we didn't realize there were other votes in play before we ran the reversal script, and the user ended up losing reputation instead of gaining as expected. But it's fairly rare that it happens. I've only not acted on maybe 4 or 5 cases where a user would've been worse off doing the reversal.

Comment: Cool. I have edited my answer to reflect the new information.

Comment: @animuson wait—isn’t serial voting unwanted, regardless of the direction? So ten up votes targeted at the same user should get the same treatment as ten down votes, shouldn’t they? Your last comment sounds like, well, let’s assume, I want to make someone the gift of eight up votes. Then, all I need to do, is give that user ten up votes and ten down votes, with the net effect of +80, and you are not going to do something about it. Sounds like a loophole.

Comment: @Holger No, the point is that there are sometimes other legitimate votes that have been cast in the past, and then something happens in the present that cause them to target the user. The invalidation wipes *everything*, legitimate and not legitimate, without regard. So sometimes it's more beneficial to just sweat out a few targeted downvotes in order to keep past upvotes that were cast legitimately.

Comment: @animuson Can you please remove the new downvotes, and possibly block the user from downvoting me again? They seem not to like me and will just downvote again and again

Comment: @animuson okay, then I didn’t understand “everything” correctly. So you’re saying, to reverse serial voting of one day, you have to reverse any vote that user ever made (on the specific user—I hope)? This doesn’t apply to the automatic reversal script, does it? What’s the rationale behind that “all or nothing” restriction?

Comment: @animuson To your other comments - I think missing an upvote is not as bad as having a correct answer voted to -1. The missing upvote and missing rep, I don't care; but future visitors will think the answer is wrong when it has downvotes. So I think it would be more helpful for the site to remove those unjustified downvotes to stop the vote from indicating "wrong" content, what the answer possibly isn't; even if it's on the cost of some reputation

Comment: @bambam ironically, when the serial voter misbehaves enough to get their account deleted, all votes are reversed and nobody cares about the net effect of the reversed votes.

Comment: @Holger No it doesn't apply to the automated script, only manual intervention wipes everything. But yes, if we manually get involved, *all* votes cast to the user will be wiped. Our tools simply don't allow us to pick and choose which ones.

Comment: @Holger I think animuson's approach is a very fair one; however, I think helpfulness for future visitors must be more important than someone's virtual reputation points. Even if it's mine...

Comment: @Holger: I've lost a ridiculous amount of rep to that. But then again I got ridiculous amount of rep from an old fastest-gun-in-the-west answer that a donor made much better.

Comment: @bambam it's not possible to block votes. If you notice  a repeat of this then do what you did previously and raise a custom flag saying it's happened before, perhaps link to this meta post, and we'll review it... We'll take further action than requesting vote invalidation if warranted.

Comment: Ok, thanks @JonClements. I'll flag the new votes too

Comment: @animuson sounds like the CM tools could use some updating to allow for picking votes to reverse instead of batch delete everything that happened in a timeframe.

Comment: @dew1 That's even *more* dangerous because then we're tasked at actually choosing which votes are targeted and which are not, which isn't a simple task and would lead to a lot of errors. The point of all or nothing is simplifying the process. Once we find evidence that there was targeted voting, we can simply assume that nome of them can be trusted and the slate should be wiped clean for a fresh start.

Comment: @animuson From most of the serial voting I've seen, I can definitely understand that line of thinking. quite a few people only get caught because they got greedy at some point and prior incidents never made a blip before. It's like seeing a -1190 and -490 reversal on one day....

Comment: Hi @JonClements. One of the moderators has since handled my flags on the new votes, declined them and banned me from flagging. Would you have another look on that please.

Comment: @animuson It sounds like at least allowing selection of a timeframe where to reverse might be good. I understand the logic with not wanting to choose individual votes though.

Comment: Magisch, I edited (paraphrased) your quote from @animuson to better describe which votes are reversed in such cases. I guessed based on context, so hopefully I got it right.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow detects the patterns and reverses it back after some time. The same thing happened to me around 8 months ago. Someone opened the questions I answered and kept down voting my answers. The next day I got my points back with a notification of `"Voting Corrected"`

PS. It happened for around 2 days if I remember correctly but I was calm since I knew I would get the points back.