# Moderator declined to handle serial downvoting flags

Tags: support, flags

So something seems to be wrong with this one - I posted this question: [Strange votes on my account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370785/strange-votes-on-my-account) yesterday. As a comment to the answer, one of the moderators recommended to flag the new votes too, which I did accordingly.

All the flags on serial downvoting got declined, the moderator handling the flags gave following reason:

> declined - you only need one flag to explain the downvoting, not one
>   for every post

Fair enough, I've learned to only flag one post the next time - it wasn't a problem before, but things may change within 24 hours...

What I don't understand is,

1. Why aren't serial downvotes reversed only because I flagged all posts instead of only one? Is this moderator behavior expected on SO?

Comment: Thanks, it's not a flood. If it were it wouldn't be a problem @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Perhaps I should have made myself clearer... When I said *it's not possible to block votes. If you notice a repeat of this then do what you did previously and raise a custom flag saying it's happened before* - I meant for any *new* cases... not to flag the remaining votes that *that* meta post had already addressed as that'd be considered "handled"...

Comment: No @JonClements It has not been already handled - the votes are still there - so it's a completely new case

Comment: Okay - I haven't been involved in any of these so I'm probably getting confused and it's late here... hopefully another mod will pop their head in :)

Comment: No problem @JonClements - anyways, the question is why the votes are not reversed only because  I flagged all posts instead of only one

Comment: i mean... you assume that's why they weren't. Maybe they weren't reversed because they didn't appear to be fraudulent. Will just have to wait and see.

Comment: @bambam oh and just to note - moderators can't ban people from flagging so no moderator *chose* to ban you. It'd just be that a decline would have tripped you over the threshold and that triggered the system to do so automatically and isn't something a moderator would *intend* to happen.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for answering that part of my question! I get that

Comment: **Moderator note**: This is a valid support request - let's not use comments to talk about downvoting on meta and distract from the key point. Thank you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate it's about the multiple flags and how that affected the mod decision on the serial voting flags and the flag ban.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

So, as it turns out, the moderator handling the flags handled two different, unrelated cases as one. The one they handled was borderline and ok to be declined. Unfortunately, they declined the other flags without looking at them then.

[image]

---

Edit

And today the serial votes were reversed.

Comment: You are failing to understand a basic factor. We review the whole account at once, All the voting, all the posts at the one time, there's no way we review only one post, we look at the whole thing.

Comment: Okay, I feel like there's a bit of a misunderstanding here. You've been flagging individual posts and asking us to invalidate particular *votes* as you believe they were unfairly cast. That's not something we're able to investigate, and it's not something a CM would revert. Users are free to cast their votes as they wish, and though you may *assume* they're casting them as retaliation, that's something we can't prove. What you *can* flag is for systematic targeting of your accounts with votes. For example, what happened to you 8th July. That particular case was indeed reverted.

Comment: The trickling of votes you've received on and since the 10th of July do not match the profile of a serial downvoter, and is not something we're able to act on.

Comment: @Rob To me it looks strongly like systematic targeting to cast another downvote immediately after the former downvotes were removed. That's what I've flagged, and those flags were declined without having a look on them and the history of the voting. Would the link have been looked at, the systematic targeting would have been seeable. Having the two top answers downvoted, both of which have only been upvoted for over a year, both at the same time, is systematic by definition, or at least a very clear indicator for "something is wrong with the votes". It's no problem any longer - keep the votes

Comment: I've put some userscripts for me in place to not be bothered by things like that anymore.

Comment: @bambam the history was investigated. What is it you cannot understand, all the flags were tended to, we cannot see who voted on a particular post, but we can see patterns. Can you please try to think perhaps we know what we're talking about and learn from us?

Comment: @bambam no ones disputing someone doesn't like you and has downvoted your post. As I said earlier, it happens to the best of us, we're not in the habit of being concerned with two votes, that's how the site works. Learn to live with it.

Comment: Please try to understand that I don't care for the votes against me. I care for the degraded quality of the site by votes that are cast because of someone dislikes the person and votes because of that, rather than the post's quality. It's okay, I'm a controversial person and someone who makes it easy for certain people to not to like me, I'm successful with it and don't plan to change. I see that you have another feeling than me about the site's quality in regards to how should be voted, which is also ok. I've already placed my userscripts so that I simply won't see any of that in the future..

Comment: @bambam again stop shooting the messenger. I don't control how the site runs. I've been instated to enforce the site's policies. So stop insulting me.

Comment: I'm not sure what was insulting about my comment @YvetteColomb, and that wasn't its intent. Sorry if you feel insulted - again, not my intention. We can stop this conversation, I will block meta from now on and won't see future comments on this post.

Comment: Professional level "*Lalalalala I can't hear you!*". I like it.

Answer (score 6):

I declined your flags. I handled all the flags as one flag, as they were all, essentially addressing the same issue, that of serial downvoting.

Firstly, you flagged every post that had been downvoted. It's only necessary to flag one post when you have an account issue.  I counted and handled one for the serial downvoting, then counted the other as duplicate flags of the first one. This was made clear in the decline message.

> declined - you only need one flag to explain the downvoting, not one for every post

Secondly, no person banned you from flagging, it was an automatic system ban, from having declined flags. and will lift in 6 days from now.

Finally, upon review of the serial downvoting, there was nothing out of order on your account, so the flag was declined.

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

We cannot stop people from choosing to downvote content, that's how the site works. If there was malicious downvoting, we would have it reversed. Beyond that, we cannot control the way people vote.

Comment: _there was nothing out of order on your account_ ... So you want to say you didn't find something out of order on two answers that are online for more than a year, each have zero downvotes but one (from the serial voting) - (168, 68 upvotes though), and were downvoted again, immediately after serial downvoting was reversed, both at the same time?

Comment: And did you even realize that the there were 3 flags on one issue and another flag on a completely different issue? Your message suggests different...

Comment: @bambam the revenge downvoting is encompassed by the serial downvoting flag.

Comment: All else has been covered in my answer, it's becoming tiring to keep going over the same thing. @bambam

Comment: @bambam don't be rude. I'm telling you what any other mod would tell you. We all have access to the same tools. Has it occurred to you people may want to downvote you, because you can be rude?

Comment: I'm not rude. But you are seeing things that I don't see, I can't comprehend how you come to that conclusion and you refuse to explain. Sorry, it's so clear that two votes, cast at the same time on those two answers are out of order... I don't care for the downvotes, but I care for two perfect answers being "damaged" by someone who doesn't understand the system (the downvoter). If someone downvotes me because I'm rude, they haven't understood the system and should be warned for that - in the end it's about being helpful - which the answers clearly are for so many people. If I'm rude people can

Comment: ...always complain about me. I'm german - our language might be a bit harder than the friendly english, but usually I don't mean things rude.

Comment: @bambam *"Thanks for your genius judgement - and thank you for being a moderator!"* is sarcastic and a put down. German or not. Two downvotes are nothing, it happens to most of us and we learn to live with it. The community team will not be interested in reversing them. And people do downvote for the wrong reasons, just as users abuse mods when they do their job, is it fair? No, but it's life.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, I've deleted the comment - I don't think you understood what I've just said in my last comment (or I can't clearly express it). I don't care at all for the downvotes and the loss of reputation. If I see an answer on SO with downvotes, I continue my search - if they are only upvoted I take that as best practice. If you personally don't care to reverse them, ok. Sad. Another mod reversed the votes on the exact same answers a day before. The post was linked in the flag text. Did you care to read that before declining all? Did you realize that there were two different cases at

Comment: hand, that you've handled as if it were one?

Comment: @bambam I reviewed your account for voting inconsistencies. Mods cannot reverse votes, we need to refer it to the community team. We have an idea of what the community team will investigate and what they won't, by looking at the account. I chose not to refer it to the team. I can ask another mod to review this and will do so now.

Comment: yes handled them as one flag. @bambam

Comment: _yes handled them as one flag_ Thanks for stating this;  that makes all you've said before understandable - the flag you were looking at really was borderline. The 2 others weren't; a third one seems to me like being involved with the 2 others, but not sure about that.

Comment: Would you please edit your answer accordingly so that I can accept it and close this issue?

Comment: @bambam done. Glad we resolved this. It's more pleasant getting along and working together, than not :)

Comment: I can't accept that as it stands. As long as there's a statement saying _there was nothing out of order_, the answer is not correct. You didn't look into the flags and that's why you didn't see there was something out of order. I'd be happy to resolve that to, really more pleasant.